# React H1 draws a blank

Tags: javascript, reactjs, header

I'm a newbie!

Looking for some help on this very-basic handling of a login-status, to display whether someone is logged in/true or logged-out/false.

I have two components, one is the main layout that houses the 'state' of `isLoggedIn`.

The other is a header that I'm trying to pass that status to, to display.

But although the console.log in `Header` logs out the true/false correctly, when I try to print it out into an H1 element - it fails.

I've tried looking on the React chrome tools ext and alternated this to this.props.children and this.status or this.isLoggedIn but no joy.

What am I doing wrong here?

**LAYOUT**

```
export default class Layout extends React.Component {
constructor() {
  super();
  this.state = {
    isLoggedIn: false
  }
}

  render() {

    setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState({
        isLoggedIn: true
      })
    }, 2000);

    return (
      <div>
        <Header status={this.state.isLoggedIn} />
        <Footer />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

**HEADER**

```
export default class Header extends React.Component {
  render() {
    console.log(this.props)
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>{this.props.status}</h1>
      </div>

    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears to me that you are setting the state to a boolean value, which I don't believe will render within the h1 tag. If you were to pass a string to the status prop, I believe it would then render that string, same with number. Your solution here would be to convert the boolean value to a string in order to get it to properly render on the page.

Using something like:
    `{ String( this.props.status ) }`

Comment: Fascinating! thank you so much @Steve - i actually just put speech marks around the bool rather than use String() as it's not a method i've used yet. Will have a play with that next though. 

All the best!

Comment: That works but be advised, if you decide to test the boolean, it will not work if you have converted it to a String!

Comment: Cheers. Yeah, i'm guessing in that instance you'd have to run the query testing the contents of the string, sort of thing? So instead of `if ( status = false` then `if ( status == 'false' )` ?

Comment: @NewbieAid You shouldn't do that. just call `.toString()` on it in render method

Comment: What Martin said! I would leave it as a boolean for easier testing later, and just render it as a string using toString() or the method I linked above. This will allow you to both use the boolean as one would expect AND render it on the page.

Comment: Gotcha. Thanks both. @Ste